# Cpu is reporting its at 108 Celsius

Tags: cpu, temperature, sensors

My CPU in my HP Laptop ENVY TouchSmart m6-n113dx AMD FX-Series FX-7500 (2.10GHz) 6GB Memory 750GB HDD AMD Radeon R7 Series 15.6" Touchscreen Windows 8.1 1 Year warranty is reporting its at 108 Celsius but everything else is reporting 56 Celsius including the graphics card but its and Integrated GPU which is why i think that the temperature is incorrect.

Is the sensor in the CPU dead but if it is wouldn't the graphics temp setting be dead also

Comment: I think it's far more likely it's 108° F. Which would be a very normal temperature for an AMD processor. Please take a screen shot or picture of the displayed temperature and add it to the post.

Answer (score 4):

It's very unlikely that the sensor is broken. Typically a broken sensor will report wildly fluctuating temperatures or a steady maximum or minimum range temperature (all 0's or all 1's) or increasingly simply no temperature reported at all accompanied by the bios reporting the failure.

In your situation, the temperature you are seeing is actually very common. You will see thousands of results if you search for 'm6-n113dx overheating' or 'FX 7500 overheating'. [Here's a forum post](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/HP-Envy-M6-1105dx-constantly-overheating-Possible-fix-but/td-p/4892560) for a similar HP model that hit 130 deg C.

The HP Envy line is infamous for running extremely hot, and if you were to search around you would find that 108 is not the highest seen. I couldn't find what the thermal shutdown temperature is for this model, but if you were to have that happen it would result in the BIOS reporting a 'system temperature 90D error'.

Here are some suggestions on addressing this, very loosely ordered on a difficulty vs. benefit scale:

1. Follow the instructions [provided by HP](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01657439) to thoroughly clean out any dust that has accumulated in the laptop
2. [Update the BIOS](http://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-ENVY-m6-n100-Notebook-PC-series/7038934/model/7450490); latest rev F.23 Rev.A was released in August 2016. [Direct Link.](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp76501-77000/sp76940.exe)
3. Check the temperature and fan RPMS with a third party utility like coretemp or [speedinfo](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php) The CPU fan should be spinning at it's max RPM (roughly 1500) when the temperature is this high; confirm that it is. If it isn't, or the RPMs are jumping all over the place and/or the fan makes a loud humming or rattling sound, then [consider replacing the CPU fan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00H49PNUM). It's cheap, and will provide you an opportunity to completely clean out the area near the CPU of dust.
4. Enter your bios setup and ensure that Cool & Quiet and APM (application power management) options are enabled.
5. [Update chipset drivers](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/chipset?os=Windows%2010%20-%2064)
6. Here is [an article](http://www.howtogeek.com/67660/how-to-diagnose-and-fix-an-overheating-laptop/) with some additional ideas

Comment: i downloaded speed fan and it said the CPU was running at 64 C and the fan was at 3100 RPM so i think speccy and HWMonitor was detecting the wrong sensor for the CPU

Comment: I could have the max rpm for the CPU fan incorrect; it was a third party source.